# Straight, dashed horizontal and vertical lines in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I need to create a horizontal and vertical dashed line. I used the paths tool and then I edit the line to do it dashed. The problem is that I set the two ends of the line manually and I cannot be sure if the line is perfectly horizontal/vertical. Is there a way to set the coordinate of the two points defining the line?

Comment: Have you tired configuring the grid, enable the grid, then enable snap to grid?  It works with the pen tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can set [guides](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-image-guides.html), that will help you put the two extremities on the same horizontal/vertical line.

Another solution is to do a rectangle selection where the edges of the rectangle are the lines you want to create. Then either:

- `Edit>Stroke selection` (with a dashed line)
- Remove the unwanted parts (eraser)

Or

- `Select>To path` (makes a path with 4 points, where everything is perfectly horizontal and vertical)
- Delete the sides and anchor point you don't need (Ctrl-Shift-click on them in the path editor)
- `Select>None` (otherwise only half of the line will be drawn)
- `Edit>Stroke path` (with a dashed line)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Ctrl` after you press `Shift` to use Angle Lock (which works at 15 degree increments). It works very nicely for vertical and horizontal lines.